# Wrong value on the question counter

Tags: bug, new-nav

I was on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/?page=1&pageSize=15&layout=expanded) and even though it showed some questions, the counter was in 0:

[image]

Comment: I wanted to delete this Q as it's a duplicate. But I can't...